# Spring Controller is not accepting the file sent by the angular controller

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm posting some form data to the Spring controller and if it is successful, again I'm posting two files from Angular controller to Spring controller:

```
$http.post('userdetails', formData).success(function(response) {
  if ($scope.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
      $scope.uploadItem(response.id, $scope.items[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

This is my uploadItem function:

```
$scope.uploadItem = function(id, file) {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('id', id);
  data.append('file', file);

  $http.post('multipleSave', data, {
    transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
      return data;
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': undefined
    }
  }).success(function(data) {
    $log.debug("Upload Successfull");
    $log.debug("File upload: Success calling ");
    alert(data);
    alert("hi");
  }).error(function(error) {
    $log.debug("Upload failure");
    alert(error);

  });
};
```

This is my Spring Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/multipleSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void UploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        Iterator<String> itr=request.getFileNames();

        MultipartFile file=request.getFile(itr.next());

        String fileName=file.getOriginalFilename();
        System.out.println(fileName);
    }
```

Content in the MultipartHttpServletRequest request is empty.

Comment: how are you populating `$scope.items`?

Comment: $scope.addItem = function (item)
        {   
         
         if ($scope.item.file != undefined){
          $scope.items.push( $scope.item);
          $scope.item = {};
        }

Answer (score 0):

You should have encryption type set to `multipart/form-data` in your request headers.

```
$http.post('multipleSave', data, {
      transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
          return data;
      },
      headers: { 
         'Content-Type': undefined,
         enctype:'multipart/form-data'
      }
})
```

Comment: @Yogesh does it helped?

Comment: I Tried with enctype but no luck

Comment: any solution do you have?